# como graficar en seaborn un array multidimensional?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

quizas alguno me pueda ayudar :)
tengo un array de este estilo

```
[['Agua de Dios',
  Aptitud baja       6
  No apta            4
  Aptitud media      1
  Exclusión legal    1
  Name: apt, dtype: int64],
 ['Albán',
  No apta            71
  Aptitud alta       22
  Aptitud media       8
  Exclusión legal     2
  Name: apt, dtype: int64],
 ['Anapoima',
  No apta            56
  Aptitud media      43
  Aptitud baja       19
  Exclusión legal     9
  Aptitud alta        5
  Name: apt, dtype: int64]]
```

y quiero hacer esa grafica mediante seaborn, como se podria hacer?

```
sns.barplot(x=y[0], y=y[1], data=dt, order=['Aptitud alta','Aptitud media', 'Aptitud baja', 'No apta', 'Exclusión legal'])
```